# interface builder: What is font size unit?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is it in pixel?
Also, does it have a one-one relationship with the font in popular image editor's font size? (such as Photoshop).

Answer (score 3):

Font sizes are nominally specified in points, where 1 point = 1/72" inch. This is true not just in IB and Xcode, but pretty much across the board. Whenever you specify a font size in a MacOS (X or classic) application, including Photoshop, the units are points. I'd imagine that's true on Windows as well.

Bear in mind that type using the same font and size may be rendered differently on different displays, depending on the display resolution, so "1 point" may not really correspond to 1/72" on screen. Early Macs had displays that were very close to 72dpi, so they were very [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG).

Comment: 1 point should always correspond to 1/72". It is a screen resolution independent unit. If you had two 15" MacBooks next to each other. One retina, and one not. With some text set to 16pt, then they will look identical (except the retina rendered font will be sharper).

Something that does affect the size is the system scaling setting.

Comment: @AdamHarte What you describe is the ideal, but it's far from reliable. When I say *resolution* I'm using the common meaning of *display dimensions*, and changing those dimensions is exactly the same as changing the display scaling setting or just using two monitors set to different resolutions. **Bottom line:** Don't count on the units used for drawing in a context to match real-world units when the context is rendered on the screen. Scaling can take place at several points in the drawing process, and not all of them are even known to the drawing engine.